# Google form regex for numbers with comma as decimal separator

Tags: regex, number-formatting, google-forms

I'm trying to figure out a regex to be used in Google Forms data validation for numbers with comma as a decimal separator.

Examples of valid entries:

```
123,5 ; 1 ; 0,1 ; 0,001
```

Examples of invalid entries:

```
123.5 ; [a-z] ; any characters other than numbers
```

I've already tried `^[1-9]\d*(,\d+)?$` but it doesn't seem to accept commas.

Comment: That regex looks fine in general, but doesn't accept any values less than one, like `0,01`

Comment: does your data come exactly as you describe? in which case your regex will not match. it would only match if the entry is "123,5" with no spaces or anything else.

Comment: try "^( *(\d*)(,\d+)* *;?)+$"

Comment: As you suggested, I just tried "^ *([1-9]\d*(,\d+)? *;?)+$"  but it doesn't accept commas or any number starting with 0, like 0,1,

Comment: fixed the expression in the comment and writing an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

123,5 ; 1 ; 0,1 ; 0,001

**RegExp**

```
[\d*.\,{1}\;{1}]
```

**Try it:** http://regexr.com/3f0r0

Comment: I think I wasn't able to explain my issue correctly, but based on your answer, I used 

^[\d*\,{1-9}]*$ 

and it did the trick. Basically, it validades only positive numbers with or without decimal places, using comma as the decimal separator, which was exactally what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any idea how I can update ^[\d*\,{1-9}]*$ to validade only numbers with two decimal places?

Comment: Try it: ^[0-9]+(\,[0-9]{1,2}) or ^[\d]+(\,[\d]{2})

Answer (score 0):

Following will match integer and decimal numbers

`(?:\d*\,)?\d+`

I think you use comma for decimal numbers.